# Proving $\left\lVert f\right\rVert_{\infty}:=\sup_{x \in X}\left\lVert f(x)\right\rVert_2$ is finite and the norm of a continuous subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces

I'm trying to answer this Real Analysis question below,

> Let $K$ be a compact subset of $R^2$, and let $C(K,\mathbb R^m)$ denote the vector space of all continuous functions from $K$ into $\mathbb R^m$. Show that for $f$ in $C(K,\mathbb R^m)$ , the quantity $\left\lVert f\right\rVert_{\infty}:=\sup_{x \in X}\left\lVert f(x)\right\rVert_2$ is finite and $\left\lVert 
>  \cdot\right\rVert_\infty$ is the norm on $C(K,\mathbb R^m)$.

I have absolutely no idea how to answer this question. I have a very basic understand for the Uniform Norm and a very basic understanding of compactness (I understand the definitions and nothing else). All I can figure out about this question is how to state the expansion of a two-norm,

$\left\lVert f(x)\right\rVert_2=(\sum_{n=1}^{m}|f_n(x)|^2)^{1/2}$

Could I please receive some hints on how I'm supposed to solve this question? I'm extremely incapable with abstract mathematics so keeping the hints very simple would help a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of a function is $\left\|f(x)\right\|_2$? What do you know about such functions on compact domains?

Comment: Would $\left\|f(x)\right\|_2$ be a convergent function? So we'd have to prove that the sum $(\sum_{n=1}^{n}|f(x)|^2)^{1/2}$ tends to a finite number for all chosen values of $x$?

Comment: It's not "convergent", which applies to sequences. Try listing out all the functional properties you know (analytic, etc) and see which ones apply to the 2-norm.

Comment: Well, some function properties I know are analytic, invertible, continuous/non-continuous, piecewise, differentiable...I'm not able to figure out how any of these could apply to the 2-norm. Analyticity seems like it may work: function $f(z)$ is called analytic at a point $z_0$ if it has a power series expansion that converges in some disk about this point. It seems like this may have something do to with proving that the 2-norm exists as it is a series itself

Comment: Any particular property that would interact with compact domains? (It's not analyticity)

Comment: By "interact with compact domains" do you mean the function exists on the boundaries of a set? I don't know what specific function property this would be to apply to a 2-norm. I'm quite exceptionally awful at abstract math, I'm sorry.

Comment: What theorems do you know that relate to: functions, particularly its values, and care about the domain being compact?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know. I am really trying. Compact is when a set is closed and bounded...any continuous function that exists on its boundaries is said to exist in a closed set. But I can't figure out what unique property or definition would allow me to relate functions on closed sets to the definition of a 2-norm.

Comment: Go look at continuity then - is 2-norm continuous? Then, what do you know about *values* of continuous functions, particularly the supremum (as you need to deal with)? Anything on compact domains?

Comment: I give up. I'm too retarded for this subject. I'm incapable of understanding how the supremum and compactness relates to continuity. Sorry for wasting your time.